# Randomly getting Apache test page instead of website

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have several websites on one server. They all share the same IP address but have different subdomains. I recently installed a SSL wildcard certificate. Now, out of the blue, the web call returns the Apache test page instead of the website. If I restart Apache, the problem goes away on that web site (for the moment) but then appears on another one of the websites. It's whack-a-mole.

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2, I should be able to do name-based hosting with SSL (I'm on RHEL 7 and Apache 2.4.6). In particular, it says "Note that if you have a wildcard SSL certificate, ... you can use SSL on name-based virtual hosts without further workarounds."

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Here's one of my conf files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerAdmin ylnsys@yln.info

             DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tps
             ServerName tpstest.yln.info

             Redirect / https://tpstest.yln.info

             <more directives here>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tps
        ServerName tpstest.yln.info

        <more directives here>
</VirtualHost>
```

The certificate information is in ssl.conf. Do I need to include the SSL file paths in each of .conf files? Yes, no?

Thanks!

Edit: httpd -S added

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ylntest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ylntest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost helptest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/requesttracker.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost tpstest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/tps.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost wikitest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/wiki.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost districtdev.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ycfld.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ylndev.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ylndev.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ylntest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf:47)
         port 443 namevhost ylntest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf:47)
         port 443 namevhost helptest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/requesttracker.conf:25)
         port 443 namevhost ylndev.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost tpstest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/tps.conf:25)
         port 443 namevhost wikitest.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/wiki.conf:22)
         port 443 namevhost ylndev.yln.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ylndev.conf:46)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-proctbl: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-pipe: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODPERL2
User: name="apache" id=48 not_used
Group: name="apache" id=48 not_used
```

Comment: Which one of those names was showing the Apache test page at the time you ran `httpd -S`?

Comment: wikitest.yln.info